# Select rows according to part of their content in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataframe and the `Pandas` library and I would like to select all those rows of my `payload` column that its first two characters are "3c" and also those rows in which in this column its last two characters end in "3e".

I know that applying a conditional would be done in the following way,

```
new_df = df.loc[df['column'] == 'condition']]
```

And that you can search if a column contains a part of a string,

```
new_df = df[df[df['column']].str.contains('X', case=False)]
```

My question would be, how can I specify that I only want the first two characters?
Is it possible to apply a logical `OR` and search the first two characters for a value and the last two for another value?

I have tried things similar to the following but I don't get what I want,

```
new_df= df[df['payload'][:2].str.contains('3c', case=False)]
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain both conditions by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
new_df = df[df['payload'].str.startswith('3c') | df['payload'].str.endswith('3e')]
```

If need both cases:

```
new_df = df[df['payload'].str.startswith(('3c', '3C')) | 
            df['payload'].str.endswith(('3e', '3E'))]
```

Your solution is possible modify by selecting by `str` for first or last 2 values:

```
df[df['payload'].str[:2].str.contains('3c', case=False) |
   df['payload'].str[-2:].str.contains('3e', case=False)
```